# Google OAuth 2.0 Playground Step 1 Authorize APIs 404 not found

Tags: google-oauth

it's my first time to ask question on stackoverflow.

I am trying to write some data from Raspberry Pi to Google Sheets directly, and followed this article "Get Credentials for Google Spreadsheet" https://docs.wso2.com/display/IntegrationCloud/Get+Credentials+for+Google+Spreadsheet to get authentification.

Everything was smooth till Google OAuth 2.0 Playground. I sellected all URLs under Google Sheets API V4, then clicked "Authorize APIs". I got the message: "404 Not Found The resource could not be found."

Please advise the possible steps which I may did wrong, then I can try to figure out the solution. Thank you.

Comment: YOu mean all the scopes under google sheets?

Comment: Yes, I plan to write data to a Google Sheets which is dedicated for this application on Raspberry Pi.